In R, what is the most efficient way to column-wise bind ('cbind()') a numeric matrix with a large filebacked big.matrix?
In order to analyze genome-wide association data with a particular modeling tool, I need a design matrix X that has columns for both the non-genomic factors for which I want to adjust and the genomic features. To create such a matrix, I need a function that acts like cbind() -- in particular, I need to column-wise combine the in-memory matrix A of non-genomic predictors with the filebacked matrix B of genomic predictors. Note that B will have type = 'raw' (coming from an upstream function in the script), as all values in B are 0, 1, or 2. I need something like C <- cbind(A, B), where C is a filebacked matrix with type = 'double'.
Here is the draft of my function:
#' a cbind() function for high-dim data
#'
#' @param A in-memory data (a numeric matrix)
#' @param B file-backed data (a filebacked.big.matrix with type = 'raw')
#' @param C file-backed placeholder for combined data (a filebacked.big.matrix with type = 'double')
#' @param quiet Logical
#'
#' @return C, filled in with all column values of A and B combined
big_cbind <- function(A, B, C, quiet){
  
  if (!quiet) {
    pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = ncol(A) + ncol(B), style = 3)
  }
  # cat("fill in first few columns of C with A\n")
  # fill in first few columns of C with A
  for (j in 1:ncol(A)) {
    C[, j] <- A[, j, drop=TRUE]
    if (!quiet) {
    }
  }

  # cat("fill in the rest of the columns of C with B")
  # fill in the rest of the columns of C with B
  for (j in 1:ncol(B)) {
    C[, j + ncol(A)] <- as.numeric(B[, j, drop=TRUE])
    
    if (!quiet) setTxtProgressBar(pb, j)
    
  }
  
  if (!quiet) {
    close(pb)
  }
  
  return(C)
}

The example below shows that the function above is both (1) slow and (2) taking up memory in the R session. Problem (1) is a challenge I anticipated; problem (2) is counterintuitive to me. At what point in the example below is data from a filebacked object getting read into or stored in memory?
library(bigstatsr)
library(bigmemory)

# n = number of observations
n <- 2000
# p = number of features (e.g., # of SNPs) 
# Note: this is unrealistically small 'p' for GWAS - I have about 500,000 SNPs in 
#   my real data
p <- 50000

# matrix of non-genetic predictors (e.g., age, sex, ...)
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*2), n, 2)

# matrix of genotype data from PLINK files 
fake_bin_data <- sample(0:2, size = n*p, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2))
B <- matrix(fake_bin_data, n, p) |> bigstatsr::as_FBM(type = 'raw') 
B <- B$bm() # need this to be a big.matrix for my current implementation 


C <- bigstatsr::FBM(nrow = nrow(B), 
         ncol = ncol(A) + ncol(B),
         type = 'double')
C <- C$bm()

Look at memory at this point:
sort(sapply(ls(), function(x){object.size(get(x))}))

Now observe how much time/memory big_cbind() is using:
system.time(
  C <- big_cbind(A, B, C, quiet = FALSE)
)

C[1:20,1:10] # desired outcome: design matrix representing all predictors

# see how much memory is used now
sort(sapply(ls(), function(x){object.size(get(x))}))

Moreover, my RStudio environment says that current memory usage is over 1.5 GB. As I scale up to GWAS-sized data, this becomes a real issue. Any ideas on what is going on in my function that make the memory usage increase? Or suggestions on how I could make this more efficient?

This is really not the solution I would recommend as it will require x8 space (going from raw to double). In bigstatsr/bigsnpr, I manage to use the two matrices without actually cbinding them. Instead, what I use in Rcpp is a clever accessor that behaves as if I had cbinded the FBM + mat: https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/blob/master/inst/include/bigstatsr/BMAcc.h#L132-L170. If you use something like matrix algebra, you can design your algorithm to reconstruct each block, etc.

@F.Privé thank you for your reply -- I have heavily referenced your packages in my own work. Clarifying question: I realize that the .bk file will require more space to store the 'double' matrix than the 'raw' matrix. Could you help me understand why the approach above is taking up space in the memory of the current R session? I want to know why the current approach is reading file-backed data into memory...

You can open issues on the GitHub repo if you want to have more in-depth discussions about the package.
